# Get top UIViewController when use SWRevealViewController

Tags: ios, swrevealviewcontroller

My project use [SWRevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController) with tab bar controller. And I use below code to get the visible view controller:

```
- (UIViewController*) topMostController
{
    return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController];
}

- (UIViewController*)topViewControllerWithRootViewController:(UIViewController*)rootViewController {
    if ([rootViewController isKindOfClass:[UITabBarController class]]) {
        UITabBarController* tabBarController = (UITabBarController*)rootViewController;
        return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:tabBarController.selectedViewController];
    } else if ([rootViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
        UINavigationController* navigationController = (UINavigationController*)rootViewController;
        return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:navigationController.visibleViewController];
    } else if (rootViewController.presentedViewController) {
        UIViewController* presentedViewController = rootViewController.presentedViewController;
        return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:presentedViewController];
    } else {
        return rootViewController;
    }
}
```

But when I standing at `MessageViewController`, or anything else I always get `SWRevealViewController` for the top. Please correct me the right way to get the visible view controller in this case.

Comment: Have you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @Hemang: Yep, but now so busy to post my answer to help for another who face the same problem.

Comment: It would be great if you post your answer that will be helpful everyone.

Answer (score 2):

- Check the hierarchy when using SWRevealController with tabbar and navigate accordingly.

its SWRevealController->tabbarcontroller->navigationcontroller->lastobject in the navigation controller. If different adjust accordingly. e.g code with this hierarchy is provided.

```
(UIViewController*) visibleViewControllerWhenUsingSWRevealController  {

    if ([swRevealController.frontViewController isKindOfClass:[UITabBarController class]]) {

        UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)mainRevealController.frontViewController;

        if ([tabBarController.selectedViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
             UINavigationController *navigationController = tabBarController.selectedViewController;
             return ( [[navigationController viewControllers] lastObject]) ;
        }
    }  

    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know its very late to answer this, but maybe this will help someone as I was unable to find a solution for this recently. My answer is for swift users:

```
extension UIApplication {
class func topViewController() -> UIViewController? {
    var topVC = shared.keyWindow!.rootViewController
    while true {
        if let presented = topVC?.presentedViewController {
            topVC = presented
        } else if let nav = topVC as? UINavigationController {
            topVC = nav.visibleViewController
        } else if let tab = topVC as? UITabBarController {
            topVC = tab.selectedViewController
        }else if let swRVC = topVC as? SWRevealViewController {
            topVC = swRVC.frontViewController
        } else {
            break
        }
    }
    return topVC
}
}
```

Comment: Superb Khan Sab...!!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help to find out the `frontViewController` of  `SWRevealViewController`

```
- (UIViewController*)topViewController {
    UIViewController *view= [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController];
    return view;
}


- (UIViewController*)topViewControllerWithRootViewController:(UIViewController*)rootViewController {
    if ([rootViewController isKindOfClass:[UITabBarController class]]) {
        UITabBarController* tabBarController = (UITabBarController*)rootViewController;
        return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:tabBarController.selectedViewController];
    } else if ([rootViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
        UINavigationController* navigationController = (UINavigationController*)rootViewController;
        return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:navigationController.visibleViewController];
    }else if ([rootViewController isKindOfClass:[SWRevealViewController class]]) {
        SWRevealViewController* viewcontroller = (SWRevealViewController*)rootViewController;
        return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:viewcontroller.frontViewController];
    }

    else if (rootViewController.presentedViewController) {
        UIViewController* presentedViewController = rootViewController.presentedViewController;
        return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:presentedViewController];
    } else {
        return rootViewController;
    }
}
```